# Highcharts HIExporting part is not working for android studio java apps

Tags: java, android-studio, highcharts

I tried to get all export options in my android mobile app, which we are able to get on a web app (9 options for each graphs),
but in mobile app --> android studio it's not working, how can i get it?
i need that 9 options to be done on my mobile app android one is there any possibility?

These are the option which i need it for mobile app higchart also and which is not working for the moment

[image]

I tried https://www.highcharts.com/demo/android/line-basic sample code and export options are not working on mobile android studio part

https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-android/issues/149 <--Here they are saying we can't have that options, is it still same as we can't have it or can we have it(can see 9 export options?)

Comment: I am afraid that this option is still not implemented and it wouldn't work.

Comment: But in some reference pages its saying as we can have that options

Comment: The Github link that you shared belongs to the official Highcharts-android wrapper creator.

Comment: Sorry, what do you means?.

Comment: I mean that the Github link which you have shared provides true information that you can't have that option, because they are still not implemented. That repo belongs to the official Highcharts-android wrapper creator.

Comment: so, there is no solution for this issue for the moment?.

Comment: I am afraid not.

Comment: @TharminiAnandasivanesan any update on that ?

Comment: Yes, I found the solution for all option to work on mobile app